# Dump process core without killing the process

Tags: process, core-dump, debugging, gdb

Is there a way to get a core dump (or something similar) for a process without actually killing the processes? I have a multithreaded python process running on an embedded system. And I want to be able to get a snapshot of the process under normal conditions (ie with the other processes required to be running), but I don't have enough memory to connect gdb (or run it under gdb) without the python process being the only one running.

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: If this is only while you're debugging, have you considered something crazy like swap on an NFS file or a network block device?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The usual trick is to have something (possibly a signal like `SIGUSR1`) trigger the program to `fork()`, then the child calls `abort()` to make itself dump core.

```
from os import fork, abort
(...)
def onUSR1(sig, frame):
    if os.fork == 0:
        os.abort
```

and during initialization

```
from signal import signal, SIGUSR1
from wherever import onUSR1
(...)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, wherever.onUSR1)
```

Used this way, `fork` won't consume much extra memory because almost all of the address space will be shared (which is also why this works for generating the core dump).

Once upon a time this trick was used with a program called `undump` to generate an executable from a core dump to save an image after complex initialization; `emacs` used to do this to generate a preloaded image from `temacs`.

Comment: Doesn't quite work for multithreaded processes, unfortunately :/

Comment: Where should I call fork()?

Answer (score 8):

You could try using `gcore`. Is that an option for you?

Comment: At some point gcore was a stand-alone program but I don't think it's part of the gdb package anymore - however you can run gdb --pid=<PID> and then use it's gcore command to dump a core file. gcore.c is a fairly simple program that is easily googlable if you want something lighter weight.